# adminjs - resource custom component for edit does not update values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-bro, adminjs

I am having some trouble using customize component for one of my resources fields. For my servicesubcategory, I have a field call parent_service_id, which has a belongs to relationship with another model servicecategory. When I use my customize component for the field parent_service_id and I try to update the field to a different value it is not reading the new value. I am using react-select to update the new field. When using console.log(), I can check the component state is changed. I checked the payload upon submit but the parent_service_id remains the same. Other field using the default component works without issue.
below is my servicesubcategory model

```
const ServiceSubCategory = db.sequelize.define("service_sub_categories", {
  name_en: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name_cn: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name_zh: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  parent_service_id: {
    type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  parent_service_new_id: {
    type: db.Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
    allowNull: true,
  },

});
const options = {
  properties: {
   
    parent_service_id: {
      components: {
        list: AdminJS.bundle('./../../components/admin/service_sub_categories/list_service_category_id_field.jsx'),
        show: AdminJS.bundle('./../../components/admin/service_sub_categories/show_service_category_id_field.jsx'),
        edit: AdminJS.bundle('./../../components/admin/service_sub_categories/edit_service_category_id_field.jsx')
      },
    },
  },
};
module.exports = {
  options,
  resource: ServiceSubCategory,
};
```

my custom edit component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import {FormGroup, FormMessage} from "@adminjs/design-system";
import { Label } from '@adminjs/design-system'
class SelectParentServiceID extends Component {


    state = {
        selectedOption: {
            value: this.props.record.populated.parent_service_id.params.id,
            label: this.props.record.populated.parent_service_id.params.name_en,
        },
        value: this.props.record.populated.parent_service_id.params.id,
        parent_service_id: this.props.record.populated.parent_service_id.params.id,
    };

    handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ 
            selectedOption: selectedOption, 
            value: selectedOption.value, 
            parent_service_id: selectedOption.value
        }, () => {
                console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption)
                console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.parent_service_id)
        });
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData()
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        let data;
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/servicecategories/get/');
            // Use the `.json` method on the fetch response object
            data = await response.json();
            const options = data.map(d => ({
                "value" : d.id,
                "label" : d.name_en
            }))
            this.setState({selectOptions: options})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormGroup error={''}>
                <Label htmlFor={'parent_service_id'} required={true}>Parent Service Category</Label>
                <Select options={this.state.selectOptions}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        defaultValue={this.state.selectedOption}
                        required={true}
                        name={'parent_service_id'}
                        value={this.state.selectedOption}
                />
                <FormMessage>{''}</FormMessage>
            </FormGroup>
        )
    }
}

export default SelectParentServiceID
```

[image: React select is showing correct select names and select values]

[image: console.log shows the component state has changed]

React select is showing correct select names and select values

console.log shows the component state has changed

[image: Payload does not change I tried changing different names for react select]

Answer (score 1):

The record is not being updated because you only set component's local state but you don't do anything to the `record` object itself which is what AdminJS uses to contain form data. You would have to do something like:

```
this.props.onChange(this.props.property.path, selectedOption.value)
```

in your `handleChange` method. However, we use Function Components everywhere in AdminJS and I'm not exactly sure if it will work for you with Class Components.

Comment: I tried to test out adding that line of code to handeChange method but after updating to adminJS 6.0.0 . All my custom component fails to render. I get this Error  

 `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of BasePropertyComponent. `  

It was working before the update. Not sure as to why.